# Bootstrap popover(draggable) jumps after dragging, what to do?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

i am trying to make my popover draggable, but when i drag it, it jumps based on the position in DOM, because its position is set to top:0 and left:0 and it uses transition to change position. Does anybody know how to solve this?

HTML

```
<div class="row">
 <div class ="col-auto">
  <h2>
    sendhelp
  </h2>
 </div>
</div>
<div id="Normal">
 <a class="btn btn-primary draggable">Popover</a>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(".draggable").popover({
    html:true,
    content: "<p>Drag me</p>"
  }).popover('show');
$('.popover').draggable();
```

**Here is an example in jsfiddle:** 
[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/153665/)

Try to drag that popover and you will see the jumping.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like margins are interfering from css. Try adjusting those.

Comment: Unfortunately that won't help. Even if margin isn't set it jumps, because of the transition. I set those margins just to see the problem better.

Comment: @Dabux Ah okay, why the translate, is that necessary? I seem to get it working by removing the translate3D. Then to get it in the correct pos on load, adjust the top and left properties?

Comment: transalte3D is there automatically by Bootstrap, if i set top and left static, i  won't be able to drag it. If i am missing something from your comment, try to post an example please.